# How to convert Java to XML using Aegis?

Tags: java, xml, xml-binding, aegis

How to convert a class into XML with Aegis?
Can´t find tutorials on the web, only random code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will save it to a file :

```
 public void saveToXML(YourDomainObject obj) throws JAXBException, IOException {
                JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(obj.getClass());
                Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
                marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
                marshaller.marshal(obj, new FileWriter(new File("filename.xml")));

        }
```

Take a look at http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.html for more info what you can use beside serializing it to a file.

Comment: That can work using JAXB, but i wanna do it with AEGIS, but can´t figure out how to do it.

Comment: @bruno, sorry never heard of AEGIS until now

Comment: @bruno - your post subject says using JAXB. Shouldn't it say aegis? Do you know why you want to use `aegis` instead of `JAXB` ?

Comment: I said aegis nobody knew the answer... AEGIS is related to JAXB, that´s why.

Comment: AEGIS is only related to JAXB as they do similar things but they are not the same thing and your question does say JAXB which this answers, AEGIS is specific to CXF, JAXB is standards based, if you can go with JAXB.

Comment: I´ve already done it with JAXB, now i need to do it with AEGIS.

Comment: Then look at the example suggested by @bmargulies or reword the question to to get answers to what you want ;-)  Putting JAXB because not as many people know aegis is not going to attract any answers you want!

Answer (score 2):

There are samples in the CXF distribution of using Aegis independently of web services.

Specifically, the `aegis_standalone' sample is what you want to look at.

Comment: That could be helpfull, how do i get it?

Comment: Presumably you already have CXF, it should have come with it or from the same place it was downloaded from.

Comment: Great, i´m gonna take a look at it!

Comment: +1. *aegis-standalone* example is located under `<apache-cxf-install-dir>\samples\ ` directory.